# dividir uma string de n em n chars, split() de n n

Tags: python

Eu tenho o seguinte texto: `"ola sou o Allan"`

Gostaria de ficar com este texto dividido de por ex, 2 em 2 chars.
Como posso fazer isto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assim:

```
texto = "ola sou o Allan"
lista = [texto[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(texto), 2)]
```

[Tirei daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9475354/1314276).

Executando:

```
>>> texto = "ola sou o Allan"
>>> lista = [texto[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(texto), 2)]
>>> lista
['ol', 'a ', 'so', 'u ', 'o ', 'Al', 'la', 'n']
```

Conforme a resposta em inglês, `2` pode ser variável:

```
>>> n = 2
>>> texto = "ola sou o Allan"
>>> lista = [texto[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(texto), n)]
>>> lista
['ol', 'a ', 'so', 'u ', 'o ', 'Al', 'la', 'n']
```

Comment: Houve uma época que escrevíamos em Assembler. Depois vieram as linguagens de alto nível. Agora as linguagens estão progredindo tanto que daqui a pouco estaremos escrevendo numa linguagem parecida com o Assembler - de difícil leitura - só que em alto nível.

Comment: Essa construção do Python para colocr o `for` numa expressão é estranha pra quem vem de fora da linguagem, mas economiza muito espaço no programa - e na cabeça de quem mantém.

Não tem muito segredo, no entanto - é como se fosse um `for` normal, e a expressão do começo fosse  o que estivesse no corpo dele, acresecentando elementos a uma lista: 
`res=[]; for i in range(0, len(texto), 2): res.append(texto[i: i + 2]) ` 
<- só que isso normalemtne fica em três linhas e não em uma.